# How to compare SQL date range in the same group and output if the range is greater than 365 days

Tags: sql, sql-server

[Sample data - please check this iamge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oV7r.png)

I need help to get the results from a large data set, where there is a age difference between a group of data.

I tried using some join statement and could not get into the loop.

"Logic: 
1. Print the first year(PROCDATE) from the same CUSTOMERID.
2. Print if the year(PROCDATE), if the difference is more than 365 days (from the remaining rows, other than the one already printed)"

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code snippet.

```
SELECT a.customericn, a.customerid, a.procdate,
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, a.procdate, c.procdate) > 365 THEN a.procdate
    WHEN DATEDIFF(day, a.procdate, c.procdate) = 0 THEN a.procdate
    END as RequiredOutput  
FROM TableName AS a
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT b.customericn, b.customerid, MIN(b.procdate) AS procdate
        FROM TableName AS b
        GROUP BY b.customericn, b.customerid
        ) AS c ON a.customericn = c.customericn and a.customerid = c.customerid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lag function in this case..

Please find the below query which gives you the expected result.

```
SELECT CUSTOMERICN,
       CUSTOMERID,
       PROCDATE,
       PROCDATE - PREVIOUSDATE DIFFERENCE_DAYS,
       CASE
         WHEN PROCDATE - PREVIOUSDATE > 365 THEN
          PROCDATE
         WHEN PREVIOUSDATE IS NULL THEN
          PROCDATE
         ELSE
          NULL
       END RESULTDATE
  FROM (WITH TEMP AS(

SELECT '10001213' CUSTOMERICN ,'282212'  CUSTOMERID,TO_DATE('01/08/2003','MM/DD/YYYY')   PROCDATE FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT '10001213','282212',TO_DATE('07/26/2007','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT '10001213','282212',TO_DATE('02/04/2002','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT '10001215','244563',TO_DATE('04/11/2012','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT '10001219','279379',TO_DATE('11/26/2007','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT '10001219','279379',TO_DATE('06/16/2008','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT '10001219','279379',TO_DATE('04/28/2011','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT '10001219','279379',TO_DATE('01/14/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT '10006912','256568',TO_DATE('10/12/2007','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT '10069018','257703',TO_DATE('09/10/2001','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT '10069018','257703',TO_DATE('01/29/2008','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT '10069018','257703',TO_DATE('06/12/2008','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT '10069018','257703',TO_DATE('09/24/2008','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT '10069018','257703',TO_DATE('10/24/2008','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT '10069018','257703',TO_DATE('11/17/2008','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT '10006403','255643',TO_DATE('06/29/2001','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT '10006403','255643',TO_DATE('09/09/2001','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL
  )
         SELECT CUSTOMERICN,
                CUSTOMERID,
                PROCDATE,
                LAG(PROCDATE, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMERID ORDER BY PROCDATE) PREVIOUSDATE
           FROM TEMP
          ORDER BY CUSTOMERID, PROCDATE)
          ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

Here I for each customer, I am deriving the previous date by using the lag function. Then you can place the rest of the logic(number of days less greater than 365 etc)

And the result is as below.

```
CUSTOMERICN CUSTOMERID  PROCDATE    DIFFERENCE_DAYS RESULTDATE
10001213    282212      2/4/2002                    2/4/2002
10001213    282212      1/8/2003               338      
10001213    282212      7/26/2007              1660 7/26/2007
10001215    244563      4/11/2012                   4/11/2012
10001219    279379      11/26/2007                  11/26/2007
10001219    279379      6/16/2008              203          
10001219    279379      4/28/2011              1046 4/28/2011
10001219    279379      1/14/2013              627  1/14/2013
10006403    255643      6/29/2001                   6/29/2001
10006403    255643      9/9/2001               72           
10006912    256568      10/12/2007                  10/12/2007
10069018    257703      9/10/2001                   9/10/2001
10069018    257703      1/29/2008              2332 1/29/2008
10069018    257703      6/12/2008              135          
10069018    257703      9/24/2008              104          
10069018    257703      10/24/2008             30           
10069018    257703      11/17/2008             24
```